# Remove all white space using "Character.isWhiteSpace"

Tags: java

I am trying to print all the words in strings on separate lines.

```
public static void printWords ()
{
    String s = "quick  brown fox jumps over the lazy  dog";

    String[] arr = s.split(" ");    
    //System.out.println(words.length);

    for ( String ss : arr){
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
}
```

The code above worked and this is the result:

[image]

Now the question is how do I remove the line with white space in between the words?

I am have to use isWhiteSpace to remove the white spaces, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
for (int ss = 0; ss < s.length(); ss++){
char c = s.charAt(i);
if (Character.isWhiteSpace(c)) 
    //System.out.println("White Space");
    retun null;
else 
    System.out.println(ss); }
```

---

Solution:

```
public class Y15Q6 {
public static void printWords(String s) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < s.length()) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            System.out.print(c);
            i++;
        }
        else {
            while (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)) && i < s.length())
                i++;
            System.out.print('\n');
        }
    }    
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split()` takes a regex. So you can specify a regex and change this line:

```
String[] arr = s.split(" ");
```

to :

```
String[] arr = s.split("[ ]+");
```

Here,

- `[ ]` forms the character class which contains only a space.
- `+` asks it to find as many spaces as possible.

---

As [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) has said in the comments below, we can also use:

```
String[] arr = s.split(" +");
```

Here too, `+` has the same role.

Comment: `[` and `]` is redundant.

Comment: @Pshemo I didn't get what you mean....

Comment: `" +"` is enough. We don't need to add character class with `"[ ]+"`.

Comment: @Pshemo Oh i didn't know that! I thought `+` only works with character classes. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Hackerdarshi, **" +"**  worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (String ss : arr){
    if (!ss.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println(ss);
    }
}
```